# Sidebar to the Right Side

Tags: html, css

So I've been refering to an open source code of a decent sidebar and decided to learn to modify it.
I'm a beginner and figured this is the best place to ask doubts.

So my main problems are as follows:

1. Sidebar will be open as soon as I load the page(I don't know how to close it)
2. I want to shift it to the right completely, how can I do this(I try to not use frameworks whenever possible, but don't mind if there's no other option)

The code is here https://codepen.io/nkrao03/pen/BaKYZdr

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>SIDEBAR</h3>
            </div>


            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="download"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="article"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>  <span></span>
                </button>

                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>
            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

ANY suggestion/help would be really appreciated.
This is probably a basic question for you all, but do bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: Fix this typo and lets go from there: `@media(maz-width:768px){` should be `max-width`

Comment: Hi! Could you pls tell me how to edit the post? :(

Comment: The edit link is available under each post. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @RobMoll Yes done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of changes to put the sidebar on the right and to make it be retracted initially.

I moved the `<nav>` div in your Html to be after the `content` which moved the sidebar to the right. Then I swapped the positive and negative margins in css `#sidebar` and `#sidebar.active`. I believe this is the desired result.

EDIT: Moved sidebar trigger to the right side.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*perspective: 1500px; */
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-right: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

  <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">


    <div class="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span></span>
        </button>

        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

      </nav>



      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>
      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

    </div>

    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>SIDEBAR</h3>
      </div>


      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p>Dummy Heading</p>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">home1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">home2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">home3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">page1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">page2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">page3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="download"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="article"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is another version that has the sidebar showing when above 768px viewport width which is standard for sidebars:

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*perspective: 1500px; */
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-right: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

  <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">


    <div class="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> <span></span>
        </button>

        <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

      </nav>



      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>
      <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

    </div>



    <nav id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>SIDEBAR</h3>
      </div>


      <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <p>Dummy Heading</p>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">home1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">home2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">home3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
          <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">page1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">page2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">page3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="download"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="article"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  </script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool!
Will practice this on my own again :)
Last question, what should I do if I want to place the button on extreme right, and be able to mimic the same button movement and the text readjustment? 
Thank you again!

Comment: @NKRao - See the edit. The sidebar trigger is now on the right.

Answer (score 1):

1. move the #sidebar to after the content to move the sidebar to the right.  Alternatively use the order property in flex.
2. for #sidebar add display:none to the css to prevent it from showing when first going to the page
3. you'll need to modify click event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', function() {
        $('#sidebar').show();
    });
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa
}

p {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display:none;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

    <title>bootstrap 4 sidebar</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
     

        <div class="content">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>  <span></span>
                </button>

                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->

            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>
            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

        </div>
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>SIDEBAR</h3>
            </div>


            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Page</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">page3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="download"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="article"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>   
        

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you SO MUCH for taking your time on this question!
The sidebar isn't closing back again when I ran your code. :(

Comment: it's not meant too.  On what basis do you want to close it?  What should be the trigger?